# Casing rows and turning them into separate columns Snowflake

Tags: group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, transform

I have a table as follows:

| CODE | COUNTRY | ID | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5109 | US | 57 | 10 |
| 5109 | CA | 45 | 12 |
| 0206 | US | 85 | 11 |
| 0206 | SG | 34 | 32 |
| 0206 | IN | 65 | 41 |
| T100 | DN | 20 | 10 |
| T100 | US | 38 | 83 |

I am trying to transform the table so that instead of the columns CODE, COUNTRY, ID, PRICE, they would be more specific on whether they referred to the US or a non US country within the groups of CODE that I have.
For example, I want the result to look like

| CODE | US_COUNTRY | US_ID | US_PRICE | NON_US_COUNTRY | NON_US_ID | NON_US_PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5109 | US | 57 | 10 | CA | 45 | 12 |
| 0206 | US | 85 | 11 | SG | 34 | 32 |
| 0206 | NULL | NULL | NULL | IN | 65 | 41 |
| T100 | US | 38 | 83 | DN | 20 | 10 |

The issue I am seeing is that within the CODE grouping I have, I'm not sure how to apply this for cases where the group contains more than 2 records (I have some groups in my raw table with 5 records for a single code as well), since a group of only 2 records could be transformed into a single row with these columns. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: In your expected output there are two rows with code 0206. One of them is NULL for the US_COUNTRY. Which one should it be? Should it be the one with the greater NON_US_ID?

Comment: They are both there because there are three records for the code 0206, and two of them contain the non US country. So lines 2 and 3 in the table summarize the 3 records because I am unsure about how to put them all in a single line, for example a line such as ```0206 US 85 11 SG 34 32 IN 65 41```

Comment: I put my resulting table to split groups containing more than 2 records per CODE group into more than one line because I don't know how to collapse them all into a single line once the grouping gets large (as in 5 records or something like that etc)

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible approaches here. This approach uses a CTE to split the table between US and NON-US rows, and then joins them according to the intent as I understand it.

Note that I changed the `CODE` column's name to `CD` to avoid having to wrap with quotes because it's a keyword.

```
create or replace table T1(CD string, COUNTRY string, ID int, PRICE number(38,2) );

insert into T1(CD,COUNTRY,ID,PRICE) values
('5109',    'US',   57, 10),
('5109',    'CA',   45, 12),
('0206',    'US',   85, 11),
('0206',    'SG',   34, 32),
('0206',    'IN',   65, 41),
('T100',    'DN',   20, 10),
('T100',    'US',   38, 83);

with US as
(
    select   CD
            ,COUNTRY as US_COUNTRY
            ,ID      as US_ID
            ,PRICE   as US_PRICE
            ,row_number() over (partition by CD order by ID) US_ROW_ID
    from T1
    where COUNTRY = 'US'
)
,NON_US as
(
    select   CD
            ,COUNTRY as NON_US_COUNTRY
            ,ID as NON_US_ID
            ,PRICE as NON_US_PRICE
            , row_number() over (partition by CD order by ID) NON_US_ROW_ID
    from T1
    where COUNTRY <> 'US'
)
select   nvl(US.CD, NON_US.CD) CD
        ,US_COUNTRY
        ,US_ID
        ,US_PRICE
        ,NON_US_COUNTRY
        ,NON_US_ID
        ,NON_US_PRICE
from US 
    full outer join NON_US 
        on US.CD = NON_US.CD and US_ROW_ID = NON_US_ROW_ID
;
```